# Is there a way to use Google maps on the watch without voice?

Tags: google-maps, android-wear

I have an Android Wear 2.x smartwatch.

I use Google maps in English even though it's not my mother tongue, simply because I want to have all Google assistants functionalities enabled as well as Android on my phone(Android Oreo) in English.

However, when it comes to dictate to Google Assistant on the watch "native to  address" it just fails 100% of the time which I find rather frustrating. so, I'd rather type the address directly either on the phone or the watch. However, there seem to be **no way neither to send Google maps address from phone to watch (unlikely other apps which have "send to watch"), nor to type the address on the watch directly (whereas many apps do have the keyboard input option)**

My question is :

> Is there a way to use Google maps on the watch without voice?